# Where can average Joe secretly hide his hybridized Mosasaurus in the present day?

Tags: dinosaurs

One day Joe came back from work and discovered a dinosaur egg of an hybridized [Mosasaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosasaurus) in his own backyard, since he is quite well verse in anything related to dinosaur he can immediately identify the species simply based on the appearance and smell from the fertilized egg. His intuition tell him that this dinosaur can easily adapt to present day air composition, climate and ocean water condition, the main issue is to ensure that this creature is hidden from public eyes especially from the scientific community which is known for their cruel handling of animal in a control environment.

Joe can easily identify all the animal genes used to create the creature with his taste buds, of course didn't eat the egg instead he simply lick the surface of the egg clean with his saliva. Regardless what present day animal's gene is used to create the creature, a hybridized Mosasaurus is no different to the actual in every aspects except its ability to adapt to any environment and climate. Joe is not concern about its diet since he can tell that the creature have powerful digestive system to accustom to the present day animals just by the way the egg rolls down a flight of stairs intact.

**Question**

Where on Earth can an average Joe raise up his Mosasaurus into full grown adult in the present day without alerting the authority or causing public alarm?

Comment: Other than Loch Ness, you mean?

Comment: @Cyrus: mine is definitely carnivore as far as average Joe can tell

Comment: The definition of "average Joe" strongly conflicts with the person described in this question. For example, I don't know of any human capable of mapping out the genetic code of a creature in his/her head just by licking the shell of an egg.

Comment: Yeah, how about "mutant Joe" instead? Seriously, how is he getting this information?

Comment: Additionally, _why_ does Joe want to raise this Mosasaurus? Just for kicks and giggles? Either he's part of a clandestine operation to de-extinct dinosaurs or this "average Joe" will be searching for answers (first on the Internet, then IRL). Oh, and he'll probably sell the thing to some dino-loving millionaire (which would be a nice twist on Jurassic Park)....

Comment: I know this is nitpicky but...[mosasaurs gave live birth](https://insider.si.edu/2015/05/fossil-proves-prehistoric-reptile-gave-birth-in-open-ocean/). In fact all of the big marine reptiles except for sea turtles probably did.

Comment: @Alendyias Economic status will also be a big deal. American Samoa or the Northern Mariana Islands would be ideal because they U.S. territories (so high standard of living) in the Pacific with the lowest density of any U.S. territory, but they may be too expensive to move to. Hawaii actually has a lower population density but the least populated  regions of Hawaii [are banned to anyone not of Hawaiian descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niihau).

Comment: @user2352714: Oof, so this would work best if "mutant Joe" _was_ a dino-loving millionaire (which could explain his odd analysis-type abilities....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "where on earth" you mean what region, I think your best bet would be to raise the creature on a remote island in the pacific.  It's probably the closest you'll get to the right climate, and the chances of anyone seeing the thing are slim to none.  The issue is that your character is, as you said, an "average joe", so I have trouble believing he would have the means to get there and maintain a place to stay while caring for the creature.

Comment: a SEA creature on an island will be rather conspicuous! I really have no idea how this answer could be accepted. It's like saying a good place to hide a Humpback Whale is in the Black Forest in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Lock Ness lake. Anyone who sees it will be ignored because everybody will think he is making it up. But if it is just an "average joe" I doubt that he can go there.